# Chrome Remote Debugging Localhost Subdirectories

Tags: android, google-chrome, localhost, remote-debugging

Following this tutorial ( https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/remote-debugging/local-server ) I managed to connect my device and to forward my desktop **localhost:80** port to a custom port on the device **localhost:8080**

Entering **localhost:8080** in the browser of the mobile device manages to open the root of my localhost (**localhost:80**)

The problem is that subdirectories don't work. If I enter **localhost:8080/site1**, it redirects to **localhost/site1** and gives 404 Not Found.

**localhost/site1** on the desktop works as it should.

Any help, please?